# #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT  departemen_id, departemen_name, COUNT(*)
FROM    departement d
JOIN    employees e
ON      departemen_id = departement_id
GROUP BY departemen_id, departemen_name
HAVING  COUNT(*) = (
            SELECT  MAX(COUNT(*))
            FROM    employees
            GROUP BY departement_id
        );
```

Comment: What does `MAX(COUNT(*))` suppose to do?  It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `MAX(COUNT(*))` doesn't make any sense to the dbms. To follow that path you'd have to use another level of inner query.

```
HAVING  COUNT(*) = (
            SELECT  MAX(CNT) FROM (
                SELECT  departement_id, COUNT(*) as CNT
                FROM    employees
                GROUP BY departement_id
            )
        );
```

You can take advantages of the row number limiting capabilities of MySQL though, and your query will be simpler and better performing

```
SELECT  d.departement_id, d.departement_name, COUNT(*)
FROM    departement d
JOIN    employees e
ON      d.departement_id = e.departement_id
GROUP BY d.departement_id, d.departement_name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: SELECT departement_id, MIN(salary)
       FROM employees
       GROUP BY departement_id
       HAVING AVG(salary) = (SELECT MAX(AVG(salary))
       FROM employees 
       GROUP BY departement_id);
whats wrong again bro

Comment: It's the exact same problem, `MAX(AVG(salary))` doesn't make any sense. You either use another subquert (select max(avg) from (select dept, avg(salary)... ) or use `order by avg(salary) desc limit 1`.

Comment: tq so much bro (y)